# Web Parsing Python - Trying to get faculty names between the 'strong' tags

Tags: python, parsing, web

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #imports beautifulSoup package
import urllib2

url2 = 'http://www.waldenu.edu/doctoral/phd-in-management/faculty'
page2 = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.read(), "lxml")

row2 = soup2.findAll('p')
row2 = row2[18:-4] 

names2 = []
arrayNameLength = len(row2)
for x in names2:
    current2 = row2[x]
    currentString2 = current2.findAll('strong')
    if len(currentString2) > 0:
        currentString2 = currentString2[0]
        names2.append(currentString2.text)
```

Here's my code and essentially I'm trying to scrape the faculty names from the above site.

I guess I'm having trouble grabbing the names from within the strong tags for all of the list of names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `for x in names2:` whereas your `names2` is blank so you probably want to do `for x in row2:` ?

Then later in body of your loop you can use x as content2 as x is not index it is the element itself

```
currentString2 = x.findAll('strong')
if len(currentString2) > 0:
    currentString2 = currentString2[0]
    names2.append(currentString2.text)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "list indices must be integers, not Tag". I removed names2 and put row2 there and replaced current2 (before findAll) with x. :/

Comment: You probably have not removed this line `current2 = row2[x]` ? You need to remove it.